# Append Series above Dataframe Column Header with Pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, xlrd

My goal here is to add a SUM value to specific columns in a dataframe dynamically through python above the Column Headers.  While I can create the SUM values, I can't seem to place them above the header once it is exported to Excel.  Any ideas on how to do this in Python?  I've tried xlrd, openpyxl, and others, but I'm not stuck with calling a VBA Macro...and nobody wants to do that. I have 47 columns and I am only totaling several of them. I am also doing a lot more to format the data later on like removing the default Pandas Index column using Openpyxl among other things.

```
df = pd.read_sql(sqlStatement,cnxn_SQL)
row_sum = df[['GROSS ACRES', 'Value']].sum()
df_sum = pd.DataFrame(data=row_sum).T
df_concat_sum = df_sum
row = pd.Series(row_sum)
df_sum = df_sum.reindex(columns=df.columns)
df_sum = pd.DataFrame(columns = df_sum.columns) 
newdf=df_sum.append(df,ignore_index=True).append([row], ignore_index=True)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(standlisterxlsx, engine ='xlsxwriter')
newdf.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

I need the exported spreadsheet to look like this:

```
                        20              100
Column1 Column2 Column3 ACRES Column5   Value
ID1     x       e       13    n         40 
ID2     d       e       7     n         20
ID3     d       e       0     n         40
```

I am using Python 2.7 and Pandas version 0.13.1 on Windows 8, 32bit.

Comment: Try using openpyxl's `dataframe_to_rows` utility.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html) with `sum`:

```
#columns for sums 
cols = ['ACRES','Value']
df1 = df[cols].sum().to_frame('sum').T.reindex(columns=df.columns, fill_value='')
print (df1)
    Column1 Column2 Column3  ACRES Column5  Value
sum                             20            100

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df1.iloc[0], df.columns], names=(None, None))
df.columns = mux
print (df)
                             20           100
  Column1 Column2 Column3 ACRES Column5 Value
0     ID1       x       e    13       n    40
1     ID2       d       e     7       n    20
2     ID3       d       e     0       n    40

df.to_excel('file.xlsx', 'Sheet1')
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on the export df.to_excel portion.  A quick search appears this function may not be available.  Or do I need a newer Pandas version?  Here is the traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
AttributeError: 'MultiIndex' object has no attribute 'to_excel'

Comment: I use `pandas 0.20.3` version

Comment: maybe miss row `df.columns = mux` - it create Multiindex. so dont need `mux.to_excel()`

Comment: I just upgraded my Pandas to 0.20.3 and getting the same error.  I tried to export df.to_csv too but that resulted in similar 'Multiindex' object has no attribute 'to_csv'.  Do I need to install something else or modify the mux.to_excel() code? Thanks

Comment: You cannot mux.to_csv(), check my answer. Need df.to _csv

Comment: I was able to export the dataframe to excel using your suggestion. However, all the cells between the 'ACRES' column and 'Value' column in row 1 are now one merged cell.  In my real code, columns J:AL row 1 are all merged together and this cell is covering another SUM value.  Any thoughts on how to unmerge the cells so all values are present?

Comment: I think you can use space - try `fill_value=' ')`